# Is there a name for this particular notation and what does it look like expanded?

Tags: logic, notation

I am reading Discrete Mathematics 8th Edition by Rosen. On page 30, the author writes

We will sometimes use the notation $\bigvee_{j=1}^{n} p_{j}$ for $p_{1} \vee p_{2} \vee \cdots \vee p_{n}$ and $\bigwedge_{j=1}^{n} p_{j}$ for $p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge \cdots \wedge p_{n}$.

This notation is used in an example a couple of pages later discussing the $n$-queens problem. Modeling $n$-queens problem as a satisfiability problem, we introduce $n^2$ variables $p(i,j)$ for $i=1,2, \ldots, n$ and $j=1,2, \ldots, n$ where $i$ is the row and $j$ is the column, and the proposition is true if there is a queen on that square.

$\bigvee_{j=1}^{n} p(i, j)$ asserts that row $i$ contains at least one queen. I **think** this is how that would be expanded out for $n=4$..

$p(i, 1) \vee p(i, 2) \vee p(i, 3) \vee p(i, 4)$

so that I can make sense of.

But then the following is given as the assertion that every row contains at least one queen

$$
Q_{1}=\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n} \bigvee_{j=1}^{n} p(i, j)
$$

How is this supposed to be written out, for $n=4$ for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already familiar with summation ($\sum$) and
product ($\prod$) notation, then
$\,\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n} \bigvee_{j=1}^{n} p(i, j)\,$ is analogous to
$\,\prod_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} p(i, j).\,$ This is not
surprising given the origin of Boolean algebra where the
value $0$ is the analog of false and $1$ is the analog
of true. Further, addition is the analog of logical $\vee$
and multiplication is the analog of logical $\wedge$. It
may help that a more explicit notation with parentheses is
$\,\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n} \big(\bigvee_{j=1}^{n} p(i, j)\big).\,$
Thus, you expand the inner $\,\bigvee\,$ first and then apply the
$\,\bigwedge\,$ next. For example, if $\,n=2\,$ then the expression
is $\, (p(1,1)\vee p(1,2))\wedge(p(2,1)\vee p(2,2)).$

Comment: are you familiar with any technique to better understand or visualize these nested logical summations? For example, $\bigwedge_{i=1}^{4} \bigwedge_{j=1}^{3} \bigwedge_{k=j+1}^{4}(\neg p(i, j) \vee \neg p(k, j))$ it becomes an arduous task to expand the whole thing out..

Comment: @RobertW I have some ideas, but that is **another** question you can ask if you are really interested.

Comment: thank you @Somos I have added an additional question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4077737/

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\bigwedge_{i=1}^4{\bigvee_{j=1}^n{p(i,j)}} & = \bigwedge_{i=1}^4{\bigl[ p(i,1) \vee p(i,2) \vee p(i,3) \vee p(i,4)\bigr]} \\
& = \bigl[ p(1,1) \vee p(1,2) \vee p(1,3) \vee p(1,4)\bigr] \\
& ~\quad \wedge \bigl[ p(2,1) \vee p(2,2) \vee p(2,3) \vee p(2,4)\bigr] \\
& ~\quad \wedge \bigl[ p(3,1) \vee p(3,2) \vee p(3,3) \vee p(3,4)\bigr] \\
& ~\quad \wedge \bigl[ p(4,1) \vee p(4,2) \vee p(4,3) \vee p(4,4)\bigr].
\end{align}